# Do we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0=0$?

Tags: summation

Simple question: Do we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0=0$$
?

Mathematically this seems obvious, but in practice I am very uncomfortable with this. Because nothing is perfect, so $0$ might not be quite zero, say $0.0000000000001$. Then,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0.0000000000001=\frac{1}{10^{13}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1=\infty.$$

Comment: Then this is **completely** different sums.

Comment: Zero is always zero.  The partial sums  are all zero.  Thus the limit is zero.

Comment: Zero is always zero even in numerical form (float, double, int, etc.).

Comment: One of the charms of mathematics is that things can be perfect.

Comment: Fantastic proof. I think we could modify it to show that no equation in mathematics is correct.

Comment: Why do you doubt that the zero in the summand might not be zero?

Comment: Could we say that infinite summation is not continuous?

Comment: So small changes in the function being summed can cause big changes in the output.

Comment: The summand is a constant, a constant function if you wish, and constants don't change. That has nothing to do with continuity. I can post an $\epsilon - M$ proof as an answer, if you'd like.

Comment: You're expecting everything to be a continuous function — your intuition tells you that, if $x$ changes gradually, $y$ will change gradually, too. (Or, more specific to your objection: You expect that if you know $x$ approximately, you know $y$ approximately, too.) This only happens with continuous functions. There are discontinuous functions, too.

Answer (score 9):

We do, in fact, have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0=0$. We also have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0.0000000000001=\infty$.

In fact, to make this more general, we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x=
\begin{cases} \infty&x>0\\
0&x=0\\
-\infty&x<0\end{cases}$$
This is a discontinuous function. (Note that, strictly speaking, this is not a function, since $\infty$ isn't a number.)

I see where your confusion comes from. For one thing, infinite sums can be counterintuitive. For another, discontinuous functions don't happen a lot in nature. We expect things to change gradually as $x$ changes, rather than having a huge jump like we have above.

In any case, the value of an infinite sum, by definition, depends on its finite sums. In fact, we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N0\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}0=0$$
(If you haven't seen the $\lim$ notation before: Roughly, it means "see what happens as $N$ gets larger and larger." There is a more rigorous, but more complicated, definition.)

The main reason that the infinite sum is $0$, is that *every partial sum* adds up to $0$. Thus, almost by definition, the infinite sum adds up to $0$, too.

And, remember: When dealing with infinities, discontinuities aren't uncommon.